# How to set a dataset equal to a .xsd file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a a dataset under a folder called DataSetsForReporting, this xsd is called:

```
DataSet_Clients.xsd
```

My question is how can i set the data set mentioned above equal to an instance of a data set in my page? for example:

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

```
myDataSet = (the data set under that folder).
```

Is this possible and if it is how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean. An XSD is a _schema_ a `DataSet` contains data, as well as (one or more) schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // Load the schema file.
    myDataSet.ReadXmlSchema("DataSet_Clients.xsd");
```

if the xsd under app_Data folder

```
    myDataSet.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DataSet_Clients.xsd"));
```

Comment: It doesnt matter where I have that data set in the solution? or do i need to tell it under which folder it was created?. Thank you for the help.